# Google Cloud Vision API multiple image annotations in one API call

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm attempting to use the [Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageRequest) client to detect 'labels' and faces in an image.

I can detect labels like [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/cloud-client/detect/detect.py#L107) with the key line of code being:

```
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations
```

and for detecting [faces](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/cloud-client/detect/detect.py#L42):

```
response = client.face_detection(image=image)
faces = response.face_annotations
```

So, currently I can make two API calls to get the information I need but I'd like to combine them into one API call if possible.

#### Update:

I found the `annotate_image()` method that can accept a list of features on this [page](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/vision/index.html):

```
response = client.annotate_image({
    'image': {'source': {'image_uri': 'gs://my-test-bucket/image.jpg'}},
    'features': [{'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.FACE_DETECTION}],
})
```

But the image source only accepts a URL to the image or its path on Google Cloud. I want to run analysis on images that I have stored locally, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `Batching Request`, it allows you to send multiple files or multiple features in one single API request. Take a look at [Batching Requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) documentation.

To use multiple features in one API request, take a look at this [Cloud Vision API Feature](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/Feature#Type.ENUM_VALUES-table) documentation. You will find all type of different features that you can request.

I did a little bit of coding myself and it worked for me. It reads an image from local storage and prints the LABEL and FACE detection results in one single API request. You can find my [GitHub code here](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Google%20Vision/multiple_features_request_single_API_call.py).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use local images. You have to put the image bytes ("content") in the request instead of "source". https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageRequest#Image

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for v2 API:

```
import io
from google.cloud import vision
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict, MessageToJson


with io.open("a_pic.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.Image(content=content)

request = {
    "image": image,
    "features": [
        {"type_": vision.Feature.Type.FACE_DETECTION},
        {"type_": vision.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION},
        {"type_": vision.Feature.Type.IMAGE_PROPERTIES},
    ],
}

response = client.annotate_image(request)
print(MessageToDict(response._pb))
```